# tree table with sortable table row in angular 5

Tags: angular, html-table, treeview, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

1. i am using angular 5 & i want to implement tree table with sortable table row, but sort row was not working with below code.

   ```
   <table class="table table-bordered tabledesign">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Sr #</span></th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Is Active</th>
               <th>Action</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="treeViewTemplate; context:{ $implicit: menusList }">
           </ng-container>
       </tbody>
   </table>

   <bs-sortable [(ngModel)]="menusList" itemClass="sortable-item" itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
       placeholderItem="Drag here" placeholderClass="placeholderStyle" wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
       (ngModelChange)="participantSortingChange($event)" [itemTemplate]="treeViewTemplate">
   </bs-sortable>

   <ng-template #treeViewTemplate let-menusList>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of menusList">
           <tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color': parameter.color ? parameter.color : '' }">
               <td class="text-left">
                   <a *ngIf="parameter.child_menus?.length > 0" (click)="parameter.expand = !parameter.expand">
                       <i class="fa plus-icon" [ngClass]="parameter.expand ? 'fa-minus-square-o' : 'fa-plus-square-o'"></i>
                   </a>
                   <i *ngIf="parameter.child_menus?.length <= 0" class="fa fa-circle"
                       style="font-size: 10px; padding-right: 3px;color: #f68c1f;"></i>
               </td>
               <td>{{parameter.sr_no}}</td>
               <td class="text-left">{{parameter.name}}</td>
               <td class="text-left text-transform">{{parameter.is_active}}</td>
               <td class="text-center">
                   <a class="iconbtn btn-type1" data-title="View" tooltip="Add Sub Menu"
                       (click)="showSubMenuModal(parameter)">
                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                   </a>
                   <a class="iconbtn btn-type1" data-title="Edit" tooltip="Edit" (click)="showEditMenuModal(parameter)">
                       <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                   </a>
                   <a class="iconbtn btn-type1" data-title="Delete" tooltip="Delete" (click)="showDeleteDialog(parameter)">
                       <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                   </a>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <ng-container *ngIf="parameter.expand && parameter.child_menus?.length > 0" class="pl-4">
               <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="treeViewTemplate; context:{ $implicit: parameter.child_menus }">
               </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
       </ng-container>
   </ng-template>
   ```

> with the using of **bs-sortable** i am not able to move any table row, so how can i implement sortable table row